# Custom post types and category archive

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, theme-development

I think this should be a simple thing to do but I'm struggling to make it work.

What I have is the following:

Custom page type called 'products'.

Products contain multiple categories and sub-categories.

The categories and sub-categories contain posts (products).

I want a custom template page to list the root categories which I've achieved by adding a template file called 'archive-products.php' - this now lists all root categories within the products post type.

Now, when I select a category I want to display a different template to list all sub-categories and products within that category but I can't seem to get it to load the correct template file. I thought it should load the 'archive-products.php' file and I could detect the category and show a different template but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I'm hoping this is something simple I've missed but I've been staring at the problem for so long I can't seem to find a solution!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) as a guide. More specifically to your situation, the "[Category display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display)" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have something like so:

- Category A (Using Template 1)

  - Sub-Category 1 (Using Template 2)
  - Sub-Category 2 (Using Template 2)
- Category B (Using Template 1)

You might need to add this to your `archive-products.php` as a conditional to test if a category has children, and if so show a different layout or design:

```
<?php 
    $this_category = get_category($cat);
    if (get_category_children($this_category->cat_ID) != "") {
        // Category has NO children
    }
    else{
        // Category HAS children
    }
?>
```

Found this answer here: [different-template-for-subcategory-any-conditions](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/different-template-for-subcategory-any-conditions) by triplebull

Hopefully it helps!

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I think I was confusing myself but this solved my problem.